# Deploy nodejs app to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, hexo

I used https://github.com/tommy351/hexo
to create a blog and hope to deploy to heroku

hexo instruction

```
 Installation

$ npm install hexo -g

Quick Start

Setup your blog

$ hexo init blog
$ cd blog
$ npm install

Start the server

$ hexo server

Create a new post

$ hexo new "Hello Hexo"

Generate static files

$ hexo generate
```

I created at local and upload the app to heroku and it reported:

```
Releasing to testApp... ....done, v3
```

It looks like everything is OK, 
just confuse how to execute command line such as

```
hexo ***
```

on heroku

I executed

```
heroku run "hexo server"
```

it always said

```
bash: hexo: command not found
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not the way you should deploy hexo on Heroku.

### 1. TL;DR - SHORT ANSWER

Hexo doc(1) says you should change your file ./_config.yml to contains something like that in this part:

```
deploy:
  type: heroku
  repo: git@heroku.com:jefficue.git
  message: Deployment of Hexo to heroku.
```

Bug for the current version (2):
You should delete public/ from the file ./gitignore. You can check using this bash command. It should return nothing:

```
$ cat .gitignore|grep public
$
```

After you should run the following command at your project's root:

```
hexo generate
hexo deploy
```

### 2. LONGER ANSWER

If you want to execute something on Heroku the command is

```
heroku run something
```

In your case it seems hexo is not installed on Heroku. **Don't do it** but you could add the package hexo to your dependencies:

```
{  
   "name":"hexo-site",
   "version":"2.8.3",
   "private":true,
   "dependencies":{  
      "hexo-renderer-ejs":"*",
      "hexo-renderer-stylus":"*",
      "hexo-renderer-marked":"*",
      "hexo":"*",
      "connect":"2.x"
   }
}
```

I've added the bold line to my./package.json and it will be automatically installed during the deployment. By default the package hexo is **not** present. **This is a bad practice** to add it. You should actually:

1. use the hexo command locally,
2. commit / push the result to the server.

(1) http://hexo.io/docs/deployment.html
(2) https://github.com/hexojs/hexo/issues/764